# Do Navigation Apps Shrink the Hippocampus?

Tags: memory, biology, psychology

A [study shows London cab drivers' hippocampi grow](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3268356/) compared to a control group of similar non-drivers.  I presume these cab drivers don't rely on navigation apps.

> ...acquisition of an internal spatial representation of London was
>   associated with a selective increase in gray matter (GM) volume in
>   their posterior hippocampi and concomitant changes to their memory
>   profile.

*Are there any studies examining the effect of Navigation app usage on hippocampus size?*

I searched, but could not find any similar studies.

Answer (score 2):

Not necesarily shrink the hippocampus, but they allegedly impair spatial knowledge - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S107158191830171X?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 1):

London Cabbies have to pass the 'Knowledge' test

> The Knowledge was introduced as a requirement for taxi drivers in
>   1865.
>
> Mastering the Knowledge typically takes students **three to four years**;
>   it's a challenge, but plenty of help and support is available if you
>   are determined.

https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/taxis-and-private-hire/licensing/learn-the-knowledge-of-london